# Client library to be used for Oauth2 implementation in Java

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to access google and Twitter API for one of my Project. Both of these can give access to there API only using OAuth2.
Which is best OAuth client library available for the same?

Answer (score 2):

Both API use OAuth 2 only and google deprecated the OAuth 1 support. It's always good to use latest version as it's more secure.

Update:
OAuth 2 has **less round trips** so it fast and quick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `spring-security-oauth2`. It is quite easy to implement all `OAuth2RestOperations`.

Create a `OAuth2RestOperations` bean which works almost same as `RestTemplate`(except for OAuth2 token handling part).

For example, if you are creating an rest call with Password credential authentication,

```
@Bean
public OAuth2RestOperations sampleROPCRestTemplate() {
    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(sampleforcePasswordResourceDetails(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(new DefaultAccessTokenRequest()));
}

@Bean
protected OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails sampleforcePasswordResourceDetails() {
    ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resource = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
    resource.setAccessTokenUri(tokenUrl);
    resource.setClientId(clientId);
    resource.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    resource.setUsername(username);
    resource.setPassword(password);
    resource.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);
    resource.setGrantType("password");
    return resource;
}
```